# cannot access a disposed object in PulltoRefresh + xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, pull-to-refresh

I used Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh.dll for `pulltorefresh` on my one child page of tabbed page.but when I redirect from other pages to this it gives me 
error

> `cannot access a disposed object of PullToRefresh Renderer`

I think `pulltorefresh` disposes of its object when we navigate to other page and when we come back to this page.it will not able to access its object so it throws an error.

but I don't understand why it is behaving like that.what is the solution of it.

please help if anybody else too faced this issue

many many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this issue by updating Refectored.xamforms.pulltorefresh to 1.1.0 and xamrin forms to 2.3.4.270.

but after this i started facing new issue.pulltorefresh activity indicator is not showing now.

any suggestion most appreciated.

thank you all.